Could Purushas of Samkhya and Yoga be the Ideas (Forms) of Plato, and we, Humans, are just reflection of them?
Could we consider Purushas of Samkhya and Yoga just the Ideas (Forms) of Plato, on the top of them Ishvara, Parashiva, who is the idea (Form) of Good?, and we, Humans, are just images of these Ideas (Forms) (Purushas)?
